# Redshift count with variable

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

Imagine I have a table on Redshift with this similar structure. Product_Bill_ID is the Primary Key of this table.

```
| Store_ID | Product_Bill_ID |    Payment_Date    
| 1        | 1               | 01/10/2016 11:49:33     
| 1        | 2               | 01/10/2016 12:38:56      
| 1        | 3               | 01/10/2016 12:55:02    
| 2        | 4               | 01/10/2016 16:25:05     
| 2        | 5               | 02/10/2016 08:02:28     
| 3        | 6               | 03/10/2016 02:32:09
```

If I want to query the number of Product_Bill_ID that a store sold in the first hour after it sold its first Product_Bill_ID, how could I do this?

This example should outcome

```
| Store_ID | First_Payment_Date  | Sold_First_Hour    
| 1        | 01/10/2016 11:49:33 | 2                   
| 2        | 01/10/2016 16:25:05 | 1                    
| 3        | 03/10/2016 02:32:09 | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first hour.  That is easy enough using window functions:

```
  select s.*,
         min(payment_date) over (partition by store_id) as first_payment_date
  from sales s
```

Then, you need to do the date filtering and aggregation:

```
select store_id, count(*)
from (select s.*,
             min(payment_date) over (partition by store_id) as first_payment_date
      from sales s
     ) s
where payment_date <= first_payment_date + interval '1 hour'
group by store_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    store_id,
    first_payment_date,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN payment_date < DATEADD(hour, 1, first_payment_date) THEN 1 END
    )   AS sold_first_hour
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        MIN(payment_date) OVER (PARTITION BY store_id)   AS first_payment_date
    FROM
        yourtable
)
    parsed_table
GROUP BY
    store_id,
    first_payment_date
```